# SQL Server 2016, history temporal table not compressed by default in Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2016, compression, temporal-tables

I have a BI database running on SQL Server 2016 Standard SP2 CU14 (13.0.5830.85) in which there are multiple temporal tables defined with default history tables. According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations?view=sql-server-2016), such history tables are PAGE compressed by default. In time, size of those history tables became significant so I took a closer look at them and to my surprise - they are not compressed at all (at least that is what SSMS claims when looking at table properties).

The BI database was created using SSDT so my initial thought was that some database publish option was set that prevented compression so I executed a simple T-SQL script in SSMS to create a brand new database with temporal table:

```
-- Create a database
USE master;
GO
 
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS TemporalDB;
GO
CREATE DATABASE TemporalDB;
GO
 
-- Create a temporal table
USE TemporalDB;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY,
   CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
   StartDate DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START  NOT NULL, 
   EndDate DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END  NOT NULL,
   PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartDate, EndDate)
)
WITH(SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.CustomerHistory)) 
GO
```

Then I checked storage in SSMS and compression was disabled:
[image]

I did the same on another SQL instance with exactly the same version and edition - the same result. Then I did it on SQL 2016 **Enterprise** SP2 CU13 (13.0.5820.21) and it worked. It also worked on another instance of SQL 2016 **Enterprise** SP2 CU1.

Finally, I checked that I can manually compress the history table so the compression feature works just fine.

So does it really work by default only in Enterprise or am I doing something wrong?

Piotr

Comment: This is almost certainly a relic of the fact that compression was originally an Enterprise-only feature. Only in 2016 SP1 was it decided to harmonize the feature surfaces and make it available in other editions as well. It seems probable they forgot to go back and change the defaults for temporal tables.